# How to insert two logos in beamer poster

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, posters

I want to add two logo in my poster one at top left and one at top right.
here is an example, I have used tikz package. To compile this code, you have to upload  "confposter" file

```
 \documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[scale=1.15]{beamerposter} % Use the beamerposter package for laying out the poster

\usetheme{confposter} % Use the confposter theme supplied with this template

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=ngreen,bg=white} % Colors of the block titles
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=white} % Colors of the body of blocks
\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=white,bg=dblue!70} % Colors of the highlighted block titles
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=dblue!10} % Colors of the body of highlighted blocks
% Many more colors are available for use in beamerthemeconfposter.sty

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Define the column widths and overall poster size
% To set effective sepwid, onecolwid and twocolwid values, first choose how many columns you want and how much separation you want between columns
% In this template, the separation width chosen is 0.024 of the paper width and a 4-column layout
% onecolwid should therefore be (1-(# of columns+1)*sepwid)/# of columns e.g. (1-(4+1)*0.024)/4 = 0.22
% Set twocolwid to be (2*onecolwid)+sepwid = 0.464
% Set threecolwid to be (3*onecolwid)+2*sepwid = 0.708

\newlength{\sepwid}
\newlength{\onecolwid}
\newlength{\twocolwid}
\newlength{\threecolwid}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{48in} % A0 width: 46.8in
\setlength{\paperheight}{36in} % A0 height: 33.1in
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.024\paperwidth} % Separation width (white space) between columns
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.22\paperwidth} % Width of one column
\setlength{\twocolwid}{0.464\paperwidth} % Width of two columns
\setlength{\threecolwid}{0.708\paperwidth} % Width of three columns
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in} % Reduce the top margin size
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{graphicx}  % Required for including images

\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\title{TitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitle} % Poster title

\author{xxxxx, xxxxx, xxx} % Author(s)

\institute{ Department of xxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} % Institution(s)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
 \addtobeamertemplate{headline}{} 
 {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \node [anchor=north east, inner sep=3cm, yshift=-2cm] at (current page.north east)
      {\includegraphics[width=9 cm, height=9cm]{logo1}};
   \end{tikzpicture}}
   {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \node [anchor=north west, inner sep=3cm, yshift=-4cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\includegraphics[width=10 cm, height=10cm]{example-image-b}};
   \end{tikzpicture}}
%\setbeamertemplate{headline} { \includegraphics[height=2cm]{images/logo} \hfill \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under blocks
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under highlighted (alert) blocks

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{2ex} % White space under figures
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{2ex} % White space under equations

\begin{frame}[t] % The whole poster is enclosed in one beamer frame
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Currently, both logos are set to be 10cm wide. Allowing for normal margins, both logos may not be able to fit side-by-side.

Comment: Can you make a complete example?

Comment: Why `tikz`? `\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\hfill
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}
}`

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: @samcarter,  thanks but it removes the title

Comment: @BetterEnglish Your code fragment does not have a title. Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: @samcarter, I added the link to the template that I used

Comment: @BetterEnglish Can you please add a compilable MWE to your question?

Comment: Many of your previous questions still have no accepted answer :(

Comment: @TorbjørnT., I make a complete example

Comment: ... Nobody knwo your images logo and logo2, so knowbody could compile your code. You could add your images or alternatvly use  `example-image-a`and `example-image-b`. - Your question is unclear for me, please edit...

Comment: @Bobyandbob, I edit it although it was very clear. I can not put every thing e.g. "confposter" file. So, I think the problem is very clear (insert two logos in beamer poster using tikz).

Comment: Problem solved?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, sure, it is since 2017

Comment: Then please consider accepting one of the provided answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use following : Please add this in the preamble.

```
 \usepackage{tikz}
```

Then, in the body of your document (right after `\begin{document}`) add the following:

```
%-----------LOGO ADDED TO NORTH EAST----------------%
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{} 
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
     \node [anchor=north east, inner sep=6.5cm]  at (current page.north east)
     {\includegraphics[height=5cm]{NSERG.png}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
%-------END LOGO ADDED TO NORTH EAST----------------%

%-----------LOGO ADDED TO NORTH WEST----------------%
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{} 
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
     \node [anchor=north west, inner sep=6.5cm]  at (current page.north west)
     {\includegraphics[height=5cm]{THALES_RT.jpg}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
 %-------END LOGO ADDED TO NORTH WEST----------------%
```

Here `inner sep` specifies de diagonal distance to the top right corner.

Please see below example. Hope this would help.
[image]

Comment: This was the most concise application for me, thank you! I am on a0 as portrait!

Answer (score 5):

I would do:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[scale=1.15]{beamerposter} 
\usetheme{confposter}

\title{TitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitle} 
\author{xxxxx, xxxxx, xxx} 
\institute{ Department of xxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} 

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
 \leavevmode
  \begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{.1\linewidth}
        \vskip1cm
        \hskip1cm
        \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.8\linewidth}
         \vskip2cm
         \centering
         \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{jblue}\Huge{\textbf{\inserttitle}}\\[0.5ex]}
         \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}\Large{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
         \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}
         \vskip1cm
        \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.1\linewidth}
        \vskip1cm
        \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \hskip1cm
    \end{column}        
   \vspace{1cm}
  \end{columns}
 \vspace{0.5in}
 \hspace{0.5in}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=47in,colsep=0.15cm]{cboxb}\end{beamercolorbox}
 \vspace{0.1in}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is much better; it resizes the title and logos.